# Accessing public variable of parent class from child (sort of nested classes in c++)

Tags: c++, class, nested

I would like to create an hierarchy of classes in c++ so public variables of higher level classes were visible within lower level classes.  Here is an example, the desired action is in "printf" of two constructors. As is now, variable a cannot be seen within class Local1. How to fix it? In general, classes will be defined in different files. Thank you.

```
class Global
    {
        int a;
        Local1 l1;
    }

    class Local1
    {
        int b;
        Local2 l2;
        Local1(){printf("%i", a);}; #constructor

    }

    class Local2
    {
        Local2(){printf("%i, %i", a, b);}; #constructor
    }

    main()
    {
        Global g;
        # want to create objects g, l1, l2, and print values of a and a,b 
    }
```

Comment: You probably just need _forward declarations_. BTW you are posting bogus code, that already fails elsewhere when compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use inheritance.

Local2 inherits from Local1.
Local1 inherits from Global.

```
class Global
{
public:
  int getA() {
    return a;
  }

  virtual void doStuff() {
    // do stuff
  }

private:
  int a;
};

class Local1 : public Global
{
public:
  Local1(){
    printf("%i", getA());
  }

  int getB() {
    return b;
  }

private:
  int b;
};

class Local2 : public Local1
{
public:
  Local2(){
    printf("%i, %i", getA(), getB());
  }

  virtual void doStuff() override {
    // do specific stuff
  }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  auto g = std::unique_ptr<Global>(new Local2());
  g->doStuff(); // will call Local2::doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply pass to the child a pointer to the parent, like in the following naïve example?

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

struct P {
    struct C {
        C(P *parent): p{parent} { }
        void foo() {
            std::cout << p->i << std::endl;
        }
        P *p;
    };

    int i;
    C c{this};
};

int main() {
    P p;
    p.i = 42;
    p.c.foo();
}
```